# Looking for a string in PHP using strpos

Tags: php

I'm trying to find a string inside of another string (I tried using strpos, but did not get any results back) using PHP. Here's what I've tried:

```
$assignedBuildings = " , building 1, building 2, building 3";
$buildingName = "building 1";
$assArray = array_map('trim', explode(',', $assignedBuildings));
print_r($assArray);
echo("Looking for: " . $buildingName . " in " . $assignedBuildings);
$pos = in_array($buildingName, $assArray);
```

the print_r gets me this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => Test Chapter
    [2] => Test 2 Chapter
    [3] => Test 3 Chapter
)
```

and when I echo $pos, I get nothing (as in "").

Let's pretend $buildingName is "Test 3 Chapter". How would I find it in $assArray?

Comment: What do you mean "$pos gets me nowhere"?? It gets you `int 3` which is exactly what its supposed to be.

Comment: @DarkWish From the strstr doc: "If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos() instead." sounds like OP has the right function.

Comment: @Vikram please post complete code that we can work with. Code that will throw undefined variable errors does not help. I've tried to restore it to the best of my understanding but you're the one with the question, so you should fix it.

Comment: @Vikram are you trying to find position or the existence of an element? The first question you asked sounded like it was for the latter but you were getting the former, but now that you get a Boolean, you seem to want position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the list of assigned buildings is a comma separated list, I'd suggest exploding it, then checking for your value in the resultant array. So, something like this:

```
$assignedbuildings = explode(",",",building 1,building 2,building 3");
$buildingToLookFor = "building 1";
$buildingfound = in_array($buildingtolookfor,$assignedbuildings);
```

Things to note:

1. You need to make sure that there are no spaces around the items in your list that are not also in your search string
2. If you want the search to be case-insensitive, add strtolower around both the strings.
3. Using the strpos function is problematic because it doesn't separate individual entries. So, if your list contains "Building 10", strpos will return a value for both "Building 10" and "Building 1".

Comment: `array_map('trim', explode(',', $assignedbuildings))` would take care of the spaces.

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo.

Change

```
$pos = strpos($assingedBuildings, $buildingToLookFor);
```

to

```
$pos = strpos($assignedBuildings, $buildingToLookFor);
```

Comment: Surprised php didn't threw him undefined variable error

Comment: I changed the typo, but still didn't work

Comment: @Vikram: it works fine for me, I get $pos == 3; If you want to get boolean, if($pos!==false){echo "is found";}

Comment: @JPR You can't: if $pos===0 (the position is from the beginning) then you get "false"

Answer (score 0):

Typo in $assingedBuildings is messing you up.

Comment: I changed the typo, but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) for case-sensitive and For case-insensitive searches, use [stristr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) 
It returns Boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `$assingedBuildings` to `$assignedBuildings` :) see demo [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/icw-fg0).